# Can I link a plain file into my executable?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, embedded-resource

Some frameworks (Qt, Windows, Gtk...) offer functionality to add resources to your binaries.  I wonder if it would be possible to achieve this *without* the framework, since all that is really needed is

1. a symbol to contain the resource's address within the binary (data segment)
2. a symbol to represent the length of the resource
3. the resource itself

How can this be achieved with the gcc toolchain?

Comment: Well, you can implement all those things, and then what you'll have is a resource framework.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: indeed, but _without_ the Gui, Serialization, XML, ... that I don't currently need :)

Comment: Yeah you'll have a resource framework, not a behemothic does-everything framework.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864866/c-c-with-gcc-statically-add-resource-files-to-executable-library

Comment: @nos: ... and that question contains the answer to my question! http://stackoverflow.com/a/4865249/6610

Comment: Precisely the same has been covered here as well: [Embedding a File in an Executable, aka Hello World](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could do this:

```
objcopy --input binary \
        --output elf32-i386 \
        --binary-architecture i386 my_file.xml myfile.o
```

This produces an object file that you can link into your executable.
This file will contain these symbols that you'll have to declare in your C code to
be able to use them

```
00000550 D _binary_my_file_xml_end
00000550 A _binary_my_file_xml_size 
00000000 D _binary_my_file_xml_start
```

Comment: exactly what I needed.  Do you happen to know whether `objcopy` exists on windows too?

Comment: @xtofl It's available on windows if you use mingw or cygwin at least, but converting the file to a C array would be the most portable thing to do across toolchains.

Answer (score 31):

At its most basic, the equivalent is a `char` array full of bytes.

On Linux you can use `xxd -i <file>` to "compile" files into `char` arrays, then link the arrays into your binary and use the constituent bytes however you please.

Here's an example from my own code's `makefile`, that creates a "resource file" called `templates.h` containing a bunch of `char` arrays representing HTML templates:

```
templates.h:
    @echo "#ifndef REDACTED_TEMPLATES_H" > templates.h
    @echo "#define REDACTED_TEMPLATES_H" >> templates.h
    @echo "// Auto-generated file! Do not modify!" >> templates.h
    @echo "// NB: arrays are not null-terminated" >> templates.h
    @echo "// (anonymous namespace used to force internal linkage)" >> templates.h
    @echo "namespace {" >> templates.h
    @echo "namespace templates {" >> templates.h
    @cd templates;\
    for i in * ;\
    do \
        echo "Compiling $$i...";\
        xxd -i $$i | sed -e 's/ =/ __attribute__((unused)) =/' >> ../templates.h;\
    done;\
    cd ..
    @echo "}" >> templates.h
    @echo "}" >> templates.h
    @echo "#endif" >> templates.h
```

<sup>(**see also:** [How best can I programmatically apply `__attribute__ ((unused))` to these auto-generated objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7660494/560648))</sup>

The result looks a little like:

```
#ifndef REDACTED_TEMPLATES_H
#define REDACTED_TEMPLATES_H
// Auto-generated file! Do not modify!
// NB: arrays are not null-terminated
// (anonymous namespace used to force internal linkage)
namespace {
namespace templates {
unsigned char alert_email_finished_events_html[] __attribute__((unused)) = {
  0x3c, 0x74, 0x61, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x20, 0x63, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73,
  0x3d, 0x22, 0x6e, 0x6f, 0x64, 0x65, 0x2d, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x66, 0x6f, 0x2d,
[..]
  0x7d, 0x7d, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0x74, 0x61, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x3e,
  0x0d, 0x0a
};
unsigned int alert_email_finished_events_html_len __attribute__((unused)) = 290;
unsigned char alert_email_finished_events_list_html[] __attribute__((unused)) = {
  0x3c, 0x74, 0x72, 0x20, 0x63, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x73,
  0x65, 0x70, 0x61, 0x72, 0x61, 0x74, 0x65, 0x2d, 0x70, 0x72, 0x65, 0x76,
[..]
  0x73, 0x74, 0x7d, 0x7d, 0x0d, 0x0a
};
unsigned int alert_email_finished_events_list_html_len __attribute__((unused)) = 42;
}
}
#endif
```

Note that this particular example is optimal when using the resource in only one Translation Unit, but the general approach can be adapted to suit your needs.